# Power supply and PWM for brushed 24V DC motor

Tags: power-supply, power, pwm, brushed-dc-motor

I've got a 24V motor with these characteristics:

-voltage: 24VDC
- rated speed 2750rpm
- Output: 200w
Rated current: 10.9A

I want to use it for a watchmater lathe, so I need to control the speed, while keeping the torque. I think that PWM can be the solution.

Which are the carachteristics for the power supply and the pwm control that I need to look for?
Do you have a suggestion for the rcheap power supply/pwm I can buy?

Comment: Something capable of more than 24 V and (much) more than 10.9 A. Try to find the stall current if the motor. If you don’t need the full stall torque and your motor controller can do current limitation on its own, then you can skip this part.

Comment: How can I find the stall current? I need full torque.my concern was about the peak current to start the motor

Comment: Datasheet or measure it. Peak current to start the motor is closely related to stall current. Full running torque yes, but stall torque?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know what stall torque is. No I don't need full stall torque, but i need full torque till few rpm. How can I measure peak current? I don't have any proper power supply now, i want to buy it!

Comment: Then pretty much any eBay buck converter with constant current limitation, or just a fixed OCP with at least 11 A and 24 V should do.

Answer (score 1):

thanks for the comments, I answer here to provide a solution if someone is looking for the same issue:

I've bought:

1. a driver AC 220V to DC 24V 15A 360W  (ab. 20 euros)
2. PWM motor speed controller DC 10-60V 20A (ab. 10 euros)